# removing weird characters from php

Tags: php, special-characters

I am trying to remove some special/weird characters from a PHP array.
The data comes in as a `JSON` with `html` like this:

```
<table class=\"MsoNormalTable\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"728\" style=\"width:545.75pt; margin-left:-1.7pt; border-collapse:collapse\">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr style=\"height:15.0pt\">\r\n<td width=\"303\" valign=\"top\" style=\"width:227.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt\">\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"line-height:115%\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:black\">Policy number:<\/span><\/p>\r\n<\/td>\r\n<td width=\"425\" nowrap=\"\" valign=\"bottom\" style=\"width:318.75pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt\">\r\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"line-height:115%\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;; color:black\">&nbsp;LAP3_MC_2011030004&nbsp;\r\n<\/span><\/p>\r\n<\/td>\r\n<\/tr>\r\n<tr style=\"height:15.0pt\">\r\n<td width=\"303\" nowrap=\"\" valign=\"bottom\" style=\"width:227.0pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height:15.0pt\">
```

I am reading the data and filtering out the pars i need using `DomCrawler` and the **output** is :

```
string(4) "�Mr�"
```

I have **tried :**

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $l->nodeValue);
```

But it **doesn't remove** the weird **diamond characters**.

Any idea how to fix this??

Comment: `utf8_encode($string)` or `utf8_decode($string)` is always a good start.

Comment: Is this only occuring when you are displaying the data? add this inside `<head></head>` tag: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: I am dumping the array out, and it gives me the characters. I cannot change the source HTML as its provided by a 3rd party. I tried utf_decode and utf_encode and it just added more whitespace to the string.

Comment: "�Mr�" means that an Iso-Latin-[12] char is interpreted as UTF-8 char, it's too narrow to be represented, so by a diamond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> ```
>  iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $l->nodeValue);
> ```

OR

> ```
>  mb_convert_encoding ( $l->nodeValue, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8" )
> ```